# Set contain only last element on calling add function

Tags: apex, collection

i wrote a function which uses set.my function is

```
public static Set<Schema.DisplayType> giveSchemaSet(Set<String> x){
  Set<Schema.DisplayType> displayCompatibleSet = new Set<Schema.DisplayType>();
  Map<String,Schema.DisplayType> displayTypeMap = new Map<String,Schema.DisplayType>{
            'boolean' => Schema.DisplayType.Boolean,
            'currency' => Schema.DisplayType.Currency,
            'date' => Schema.DisplayType.Date,
            'datetime' => Schema.DisplayType.DateTime,
            'double' => Schema.DisplayType.Double,
            'email' => Schema.DisplayType.Email,
            'encryptedstring' => Schema.DisplayType.EncryptedString,
            'integer' => Schema.DisplayType.Integer,
            'multipicklist' => Schema.DisplayType.MultiPickList,
            'percent' => Schema.DisplayType.Percent,
            'phone' => Schema.DisplayType.Phone,
            'picklist'=> Schema.DisplayType.Picklist,
            'reference'=>Schema.DisplayType.Reference,
            'string' =>Schema.DisplayType.String,
            'textarea' =>Schema.DisplayType.TextArea,
            'time' => Schema.DisplayType.Time,
            'url' => Schema.DisplayType.URL
            };
  System.debug('x is '+x);
  for(String displayType:x)
  {
   System.debug('displayType is:' + displayTypeMap.get(displayType));
   displayCompatibleSet.add(displayTypeMap.get(displayType));
  }
  System.debug('displayCompatibleSet is'+displayCompatibleSet);
  return displayCompatibleSet;
}
```

in debug log

```
x is {boolean, picklist, string, textarea}
displayCompatibleSet is{BOOLEAN}
```

in argument i am passing 4 elements but in displayCompatibleSet.it should also be of 4 length but it contains only one element .can anyone please explain this behaviour.

Comment: Do you see your "displayType is:" debug output in the debug log?

Comment: yes for loop is traversing 4 times and giving correct output. but set is not getting added 4 times.Please help

Comment: and every time instead of boolean there is some random value among these four

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With exactly the implementation you have posted this test passes so I think the code is good:

```
@isTest
private class ATest {
    @isTest
    static void test() {
        Set<String> x = new Set<String>{
                'boolean',
                'picklist',
                'string',
                'textarea'
                };
        Set<Schema.DisplayType> expected = new Set<Schema.DisplayType>{
                Schema.DisplayType.Boolean,
                Schema.DisplayType.Picklist,
                Schema.DisplayType.String,
                Schema.DisplayType.TextArea
                };
        System.assertEquals(expected, giveSchemaSet(x));
    }
    public static Set<Schema.DisplayType> giveSchemaSet(Set<String> x) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**PS** The issue is with the debug output of sets of enumerations: the sets themselves are fine.

Comment: Brilliant. Absolutely correct about the fact that the `Set` contains the correct values. Iterating over the result indeed produced the full list of elements. Thanks Keith!! Something new is learned every day.

Comment: @MarkPond Think I saw the same problem a few months ago on this site where the debug output for sets was misleading someone but to be honest had forgotten about that when first looking at this...